I need Ionic/Angular app to read incoming sms messages when app is closed
I'm developing an app for a local women's shelter that takes incoming sms messages from specific contacts, and uses AI to remove abusive language. Ideally the person adds the abuser to their spam folder in their sms app, and then reads the filtered version in our app.
Is there a way for our app to read an incoming sms message from specific phone numbers and fire the text to our servers using rest api, which would then handle the filtering, push notifications, etc while the app is closed
Everything seems pretty straightforward, other than when the app is closed. I've seen capacitor background plugins but they seem to run every few minutes/hours, and I haven't found a way to trigger one when an sms is received. This needs to work for android/IOS
We can go down multiple routes as well. If there are any alternatives for us getting those texts when the app is closed, please shoot ideas at me. Thanks!!!

Welcome to stackoverflow! Read this post and edit your question. Read this also. Be aware of Android's battery optimizations and restrictions on background services in recent versions. Consider using npm install cordova-plugin-sms-receiver I have used this in back 2019 not sure its still available and working in android 14 or not due to google policy changes.

No you cannot. There is no way for your hybrid app to communicate with the SMS native layer in the way you think unless you write your own cap plugin. So the capacitor background plugin will not work in your case anyway since it would need to be refactored to communicate with sms native layer.

You're best bet is to: use https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links, so the user can click on the link they received via sms (add custom logic) and then that will redirect them to open the app.
